# How to set httpRuntime executionTimeout to milliseconds?

Tags: c#

In c# asp.net web.config settings I have this

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxUrlLength="10999" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" executionTimeout="1" />
```

but seems its in seconds, how can I make it in milliseconds?

Comment: I believe that the answer is, you can't. Look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.executiontimeout?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-2.0/e1f13641(v=vs.80)), sub-second values are not supported in that property.

Possible work arounds: You might want to look at [HttpWebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout?view=netframework-4.7.2) or running the call on a thread with a timeout set.

Comment: is there another location i would need to edit to make it milliseconds?

Comment: The documentation on this is confusing, as it shows a `TimeSpan` as a valid value for the `executionTimeout` attribute, yet I'm finding that any value other than an integer throws an error.

Comment: @JonathonChase Are you setting the value in code and not in the config itself? That might be another work around.